# Converting string to double in fluent-nhibernate mapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a sql table with a string column that could contain null, empty string or a double value.
I want to map this column to a C# property that is a `double`, defaulting to zero when the column is null or empty.
Can I do this with a fluent-nhibernate mapping?
I tried this:

```
Map(p => p.doubleProperty).CustomSqlType("varchar(20)").CustomType("double").Default("0");
```

and variations on this theme but I always get an error that the conversion failed.

Answer (score 5):

For now I've gone with a custom type which allows me to use

```
      Map(p=>p.doubleProperty).CustomType<DoubleString>();
```

Which will do for my current needs.

I'll leave the question open for now in case someone comes up with an easier solution.

Code for the DoubleString type is below.

```
public class DoubleString : IUserType
{
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return x.Equals(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }

    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        var valueToGet = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]) as string;
        double returnValue = 0.0;
        double.TryParse(valueToGet, out returnValue);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        object valueToSet = ((double)value).ToString();
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, valueToSet, index);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }

    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { new SqlType(DbType.String) };
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(double); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this solved a case where I had to persist a custom `struct` as a string in the database! I'd greatly appreciate if you have any clues on how to modify the above so it works with `Nullable<?>` types though. Is it necessary to change it to work with nullables or I need only to play with the user type convention?

Comment: Its a very nice answer. In my case, I had to change the `ToString()` on line 40 to: `.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));` because the `ToString()` changes the double from, e.g. `1.23` to `1,23` and the SQL didn't accepts it. With the culture it keeps the dot instead of the comma.

Answer (score 1):

I would just map this to a string and in your entity have a property that is a double that does the conversion.  Seems easier and cleaner than doing it in the mapping.

Maybe something like this:

```
public double Price
{
    get
    {
        double price = -1.0;
        Double.TryParse(stringProperty, out price);
        return price;
    }
    set { stringProperty = value.ToString(); }
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure it's cleaner, I'd need a string property for NH to use when saving and a double property to use when accessing it from code. That's if I understand what you are suggesting correctly. If I just have one double property then NH saves it as a double and not as a string.

Comment: touché ... I meant to take the cleaner part out.  Cleaner as far as your mapping is concerned but not your entity.  In this solution you would have a private string variable and a public double property

Answer (score 0):

I solved kind of the same problem using two Properties which both referred to the same private variable. In my example the database contains a varchar which is NOT USED or ACTUAL, i therefor wanted a bool in my application.

```
    private bool _myBool= true;

    public virtual bool MyBool{ get { return _myBool; } set { _myBool= value; } }

    public virtual string MyString
    {
        get { return _myBool ? "ACTUAL" : "NOT USED"; }
        set { _myBool= value.Equals("NOT USED"); }
    }
}
```